Primitive element of Galois extension whose conjugates are linear dependent.
I was reading in my fields and Galois theory course about normal basis for Galois extensions and primitive elements.
The section about normal basis opened the chapter saying that we can have a primitive element $\alpha$ for a Galois extension $F/K$, but we cannot assure that the conjugates elements of $\alpha$, that is: $\{\varphi_1(\alpha),\dots,\varphi_n(\alpha)\}$ with $Gal(F/K)=\{\varphi_i\}_{i=1}^n$, are linearly indepedent, so that the discussion for finding normal basis is not trivial.
But the text did not give any example. What examples could be used to illustrate this fact, that is, a Galois extension $F/K$ with a primitive element $\alpha$ for which $\{\varphi_1(\alpha),\dots,\varphi_n(\alpha)\}$ is linearly dependent?
Thanks.

You can consider the extension $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3})/\mathbb{Q}$, which primitive element (one of them) is $\alpha = \sqrt{2} +\sqrt{3}$.
This is a Galois extension with $\left| Gal \left( \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3})/\mathbb{Q} \right) \right| = 4$, and those 4 elements are:
$$
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|} 
 & \sigma_1 & \sigma_2 & \sigma_3 & \sigma_4 \\ \hline
\sqrt{2}\mapsto & \sqrt{2} & \sqrt{2} & -\sqrt{2} & -\sqrt{2}\\ \hline
\sqrt{3}\mapsto & \sqrt{3} & -\sqrt{3} & \sqrt{3} & -\sqrt{3} \\ \hline
\end{array}
$$
Then you have
$$\sigma_1(\alpha) = \sqrt{2} + \sqrt{3},\\
\sigma_2(\alpha) = \sqrt{2} - \sqrt{3}, \\ \sigma_3(\alpha) = -\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{3}, \\ \sigma_4(\alpha) = -\sqrt{2} - \sqrt{3}, $$
so $\{\sigma_1(\alpha), \sigma_2(\alpha), \sigma_3(\alpha), \sigma_4(\alpha) \} $ is linearly dependent.

Good and simple answer @Adr3W
